# I Cannot Show Data saved In The Arrays I created

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in c# coding, and I was trying an example creating a program that saves `name`, `id` and `group` for students in any field. Saving is okay, but showing what is saved is my problem, and it always ends by giving me a handling error. Here is my code. Thank you very much.

```
    public static string [] z, x, v,s;
    public static int i = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        z = new string[3];
        x = new string[3];
        v = new string[3];


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(name.Text==string.Empty)
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(name, "Enter Name");
            return;
        }
        if(id.Text==string.Empty)
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(id, "Enter Student Id");
            return;
        }
        if(group.Text==string.Empty)
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(group, "Enter Student Group");
        }
        z[i] = name.Text;
        x[i] = id.Text;
        v[i] = group.Text;
        i++;
        saved.Text = "Saved";
        saved.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        timer1.Start();
    }
    public void clear()
    {
        name.Text = id.Text = group.Text = " ";
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saved.Text = " ";
        clear();
        timer1.Stop();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 3;i++ )
        {
            screen.Text = "Name :" + z[i] + "\n ID: " + x[i] + "\nGroup : " + v[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: `"it always ends by giving me a handling error"` - What is the error?

Comment: If `button1` is clicked over 3 times, `i` will become larger than 2, giving you an error because `z`, `x` and `v` only have 3 elements.

Comment: when i press button 2 , it shows me in the screen :
Name:
ID:
Group:

Like i didn't save any data in the arrays ..

Comment: Screen.Text = seems like it will overwrite whatever you had before.  Should it be +=?

Comment: You need to really post the error you receive <-- Most important!!!   You also need to rethink the use of i as a global variable.  Also good practice to qualify x,y and z with Form1 since they are static.

Comment: @Sorceri sorry, new to "Stackoverflow" , :D.

Comment: Your `i` variable is getting you into trouble because you are losing track of it by using it in different places for different things.

Comment: @RobP. , thank you very much dude .. solved :D .

Comment: @LarsTech i noticed that , but i won't make this fault again , thank you for this advice.

Answer (score 0):

As you say

> but showing what is saved is my problem

I can suppose that the problem is here (the only method where you show the saved stuff):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 3;i++ )
    {
        screen.Text = "Name :" + z[i] + "\n ID: " + x[i] + "\nGroup : " + v[i];
    }
}
```

You are using **i** in the **for** loop and **i** declared in the class to control the count of students, try to use another in the button event, like **j**

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 3;j++ )
    {
        screen.Text = "Name :" + z[j] + "\n ID: " + x[j] + "\nGroup : " + v[j];
    }
}
```

If is not the problem I can not think in many things as you don't specify what kind of error are you getting

Answer (score 0):

Firstly click `button 1`  3 times to read and save data. Then click `button 2` to display the results.
Also, you should use `screen.Text +=` to append previous data.

Answer (score 0):

I think modifying your code like this will fix your problem

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        screen.Text = "Name :" + z[j] + "\n ID: " + x[j] + "\nGroup : " + v[j];
    }
}
```

All that's done here is that instead of using the global `i` variable that you defined (whill you'll learn later is a mistake, but that's not the issure now) a new variable `int j` is defined in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting an error:

> "Index was outside the bounds of the array".

```
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        screen.Text = "Name :" + z[i] + "\n ID: " + x[i] + "\nGroup : " + v[i];
    }
```

Terminates when i == 3. Thus causing the out of bounds error when you click button1.
Moreover, clicking button1 4x will also cause this error.

Remember to verify index values when accessing items in an array

```
    if (i >= z.Length)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ran out of room in the array!");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have enough information to answer the question directly (see other comments), but I can make some suggestions based on the code I have seen above.

First, use objects. Since **name**, **student ID** and **student group** appear to all be related, create an object with properties:

```
public class Student
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Group { get; set; }

    public override String ToString()
    {
         // fill in
    }
}
```

Fill in ToString with whatever code you want to produce a string based on the contents of the object. This makes **Student** responsible for formatting itself.

Then you can either declare an array of **Student[3]** or a **List<Student>**, which latter gets you into collections and lets you have any arbitrary number of **Student** objects.

This will get you farther into using the object-oriented nature of C#.

Comment: You aren't actually answering the question or addressing the error.